# Searching through multiple objects in one array using For loop and conditional operators

Tags: javascript, for-loop, conditional-operator

I'm trying to create a function that will search through an array consisting of multiple objects, as shown below, and return the value of one certain prop.

```
const contacts = [
  {
    firstName: "Akira",
    lastName: "Laine",
    number: "0543236543",
    likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Harry",
    lastName: "Potter",
    number: "0994372684",
    likes: ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sherlock",
    lastName: "Holmes",
    number: "0487345643",
    likes: ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kristian",
    lastName: "Vos",
    number: "unknown",
    likes: ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"],
  },
];
```

Below are the conditions:

- if Name exists inside the contacts array, then I have to check whether prop exists in that name.
- If the prop doesn't exist, return "No such property"
- If name doesnt exist in the array, return "No such contact".

Function name : `function lookUpProfile(name, prop)`

Now i have previously succeeded in doing this using `if else if`. Now i want to try it with conditional operators but i can't seem to do it. Below is what i've written

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  for (let i=0;i<contacts.length;i++) {
      return contacts[i].firstName===name ? contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) ? contacts[i][prop]
        : "No such property"
        : 0
  }
  return "No such name";
}
```

I have followed the if else structures the exact same way i did when i used if else before. But this code can't seem to do the job. Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: The ternary operator looks like this `condition ? expression : expression`, but things like return (and break, etc) are *statements*, not expressions. The regular form would include a conditional return, like `if(name_match) return prop_match ? prop : 'missing prop';`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the condition is such a way that it will return data for the first index itself, if you want can try finding the index of the name and provide conditional return

```
const index = contacts.findIndex(contact => contact.firstName === name);
      return index > -1 ? (contacts[index].hasOwnProperty(prop) ? contacts[index][prop]
      : "No such property")
      : "No such name";
```

Comment: sorry i'm a beginner actually and i'm limiting myself to just using the conditional operators only. can you probably explain it in another way?